# MENU DINAMICO CON viewScroller.js

Tags: javascript, html

Quiero hacer un menú que cambie el nombre dependiendo en la sección en la que se encuentre, este debe estar fixed todo el tiempo, la página la desarrolle con viewScroller.js y hasta el momento no he logrado conseguirlo:

http://www.viewdesic.com/viewscroller/ <--Es la misma estructura que este

en tanto al menu lo tengo así

```
                <div id="side">
                <div class="icMenu">
                    <div class="hamburger">
                        <div class="hamburger-inner"></div>
                    </div> 
                </div>
                <h3 class="tituloSection" id="tittle">Home</h3> 
            </div>
            <div id="sidePrev">
                <a><img src="imagenes/web-mano-santa-arrow-right.png" width="50%" class="indicadorNext vs-mainview-next"></a>
            </div>
            <div id="sideNex">
                <a><img src="imagenes/web-mano-santa-arrow-left.png" width="50%" class="indicadorNext vs-mainview-prev"></a>
            </div>
            <div id="sideFoot">
                <i class="fa fa-instagram fa-lg whiteIcons" ></i><br><br><br>
                <i class="fa fa-facebook fa-lg whiteIcons" ></i>
            </div>
            <div id="menuBarra">
            </div>
```

Lo que debe cambiar es lo que dice "home"

Comment: tienes algún ejemplo de lo que has desarrollado??   Puedes crear un snippet verificable, para que todos podamos añadir lo que te haga falta?¿

Comment: https://codepen.io/Erik_W/pen/JaxZyV <-- Aquí está, ojalá me puedas ayudar

Comment: Uf!!! no se ve nada bien!!!  has mirado lo que sale?? sale un boton enorm y todo un poco desorganizado!!!

Comment: Lo que puedo decirte, es que el contenido se cambiaria con  `$("#tittle")[0].innerHTML("LoQueTuQuieras");`

Comment: https://codepen.io/Erik_W/full/JaxZyV Revisa la carga en full page, solo no aparecen las imagenes, de las secciones, el menu que comentaba si sale

Comment: Mira, así se crean los comentarios en la pregunta https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/430/16285

Comment: eso acabo de mirar, pero la verdad que no sé ni si está abierto el menú... o no... no veo más opciones!! sólo veo el boton del menu y el home..... pero no se ve nada mas!!

Comment: Si es que la idea es que al hacer scroll se cambie el nombre de la sección en este caso dice "home"

Comment: entonces, añade un "onclick" a cada una de las opciones, y que cada una cambie el nombre, no??

Comment: O lo quieres que cambie cuando se haga Scroll a mano??¿ ¿

Comment: Si, cuando se haga scroll  cambie de sección se cambie automaticamente

Answer (score 0):

En primer lugar, debes chequear el [evento onScroll](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onscroll.asp)

Al hacer el onScroll, debes [chequear que cada uno de las secciones, sea visible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123999/how-to-tell-if-a-dom-element-is-visible-in-the-current-viewport)

```
$(".mainview").forEach(function (obj, index){
   //Aqui chequea si es visible. 
   // Y si es visible actualizas el boton
});
```

En función de lo que consideres que hace visible a cada sección (ahí supongo que tendrás que mirar bien para que se comporte como esperas).

Podrás cambiar el valor con la siguiente orden:

```
$("#tittle")[0].innerHTML("LoQueTuQuieras");
```

Recuerda que en el foreach, puedes acceder a cada `obj` que localizas, por lo que puedes saber su nombre directamente, y aplicar ese nombre al `tittle`

Comment: He tratado de hacerte un resumen, no te comprendía, disculpame. A ver si con eso te puede valer.  

He puesto en el foreach el `.mainview `ya que es la clase que identifica a las secciones

Comment: Perfecto, lo checo y te digo que pasa GRACIAS!

Comment: si... siento no poder ponerte más, pero no tengo tiempo de programarlo todo, necesitaría un rato para dejarlo bien. Espero que al menos te guíe, o que alguien mejore mi respuesta / añada la suya y avancemos!!